# Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'id' to parameter of type 'int'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I guess it's really simple but I can't find the way to work this out...

I have a method like this

```
- (int)showQuestionMethod:(int)number;
```

I'm creating NSMutableOrderedSet in loop like this which works fine.

```
while (count < numberOfQuestionsInTest) {
    randomQuestionNumber = 0 + arc4random() % (numberOfQuestions - 0);
    [_randomQuestionNumberArray addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:randomQuestionNumber]];
     count = [_randomQuestionNumberArray count];
}
```

Then when I want to call a method with this line  and I get an error (Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'id' to parameter of type 'int')

```
int showQuestion = 0;
[self showQuestionMethod:_randomQuestionNumberArray[showQuestion]];
```

Can anyone offer solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Your `_randomQuestionNumberArray` contains `NSDecimalNumber` instances. But your method takes and `int` parameter. You need to properly convert them:

```
[self showQuestionMethod:[_randomQuestionNumberArray[showQuestion] intValue]];
```

Comment: this one always give a result of 0

Comment: Then you must be filling the array with zeros. Are you sure that `numberOfQuestions` isn't `0`? Use the debugger and see what value you get for `randomQuestionNumber` in your `while` loop when filling the array.

Comment: my fault. when i create an array in loop it fills it with random numbers like 3,1,2 and when i print it in NSLog it prints it. But when I do NSLog to print this array just after calling a method it says this array is Null. I can't understand why..

Comment: It sounds like you never alloc/init your `_randomQuestionNumberArray` array. You need something like `_randomQuestionNumberArray = [NSMutableArray array];` before you attempt to use it the 1st time.

Comment: i have this in my method just before loop where i fill the values in         NSMutableOrderedSet *_randomQuestionNumberArray = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] init];

Comment: That creates a new local variable. That doesn't help the instance variable. You simply want: `_randomQuestionNumberArray = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] init];`. This will initialize the instance variable instead of creating a new local variable with the same name.

Comment: Thanks, the array is allocated now and prints the values through NSLog correctly anytime, but when i try to get the values from the array i still get zero every time.. 

    int showQuestion = [_randomQuestionNumberArray[1] intValue];
    [self showQuestionMethod:[_randomQuestionNumberArray[showQuestion] intValue]];
    NSLog(@"The array is: %@", _randomQuestionNumberArray);
    NSLog(@"Should second value %i", showQuestion);

2014-03-08 18:38:49.703 quiz3[14382:70b] The array is: {(
    1,
    2,
    0
)}
2014-03-08 18:38:49.703 quiz3[14382:70b] Should second value 0

Comment: Add a log of `NSLog(@"array[1] is %@", _randomQuestionNumberArray[1]);`. Does that give 0 or 2?

Comment: 2014-03-08 18:53:24.324 quiz3[14472:70b] The array is: {(
    2,
    1,
    0
)}
2014-03-08 18:53:24.325 quiz3[14472:70b] array[0] is 2
2014-03-08 18:53:24.325 quiz3[14472:70b] array[1] is 1
2014-03-08 18:53:24.326 quiz3[14472:70b] array[2] is 0
2014-03-08 18:53:24.326 quiz3[14472:70b] int showQuestion = [_randomQuestionNumberArray[1] intValue is 0